# Mobilefirst 8.0 Java Adapter SSL

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, jax-rs, ssl-certificate, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm currently develop my application with Mobilefirst 8.0 but there is some problem when JAVA HTTP adapter connect with external resources HTTPS connection with self-signed certificate. The public certificate from external resources was imported into my server which is /IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/{server name}/resources/security/key.jks but still getting handshake_failure exception. Any idea/solution to overcome this issue?

1)So far, i'm tried build exactly same logic with JavaScript HTTP adapter and import my JKS into Runtime Setting/Keystore tab which [Configure Mobilefirst Keystore](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/configuring-the-mobilefirst-server-keystore/) worked with  within my adapter.xml

2)try to System.setProperty to point my own keystore and try to print it out when runtime but the result printed with different with what been set in my JAVA HTTP Adapter.

3)try set  in my JAVA HTTP adapter same as my JAVASCRIPT HTTP Adapter, build and deploy with no errors but handshake_failure exception return. FYI, [JAVA ADAPTER ATTRIBUTES](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/) doesn't provide this attribute.

## Upload server.xml

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>

    <!-- Begin of features added by IBM MobileFirst <installmobilefirstadmin> ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'. -->
    <!-- The following lines will be removed when the application is uninstalled -->
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>usr:MFPDecoderFeature-1.0</feature>
    <!-- End of features added by IBM MobileFirst <installmobilefirstadmin> ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'. -->


    <!-- Begin of features added by IBM MobileFirst <installmobilefirstruntime> ant task for context root '/mfp'. -->
    <!-- The following lines will be removed when the application is uninstalled -->
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>usr:MFPDecoderFeature-1.0</feature>
    <feature>webProfile-6.0</feature>
    <!-- End of features added by IBM MobileFirst <installmobilefirstruntime> ant task for context root '/mfp'. -->


    <!-- Begin of features added by IBM MobileFirst installer. -->
    <!-- The following lines will be removed when the application is uninstalled -->
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>usr:MFPDecoderFeature-1.0</feature>
    <!-- End of features added by IBM MobileFirst installer. -->

</featureManager>

<httpAccessLogging id="accessLogging">
    <accessLogging filepath="${server.output.dir}/logs/http_defaultEndpoint_access.log" logFormat='%h %i %u %U %t "%r" %s %b' />
</httpAccessLogging>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              httpPort="9080"
              httpsPort="9443" host="*" accessLoggingRef="accessLogging">

    <!-- Option soReuseAddr added by IBM MobileFirst <installmobilefirstadmin> ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'. -->
    <!-- Option soReuseAddr added by IBM MobileFirst <installmobilefirstruntime> ant task for context root '/mfp'. -->
    <!-- Option soReuseAddr added by IBM MobileFirst installer. -->
    <tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/>

</httpEndpoint>

<administrator-role>
    <!--    MobileFirst JMX User.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
    -->
    <user>MfpRESTUser</user>




</administrator-role>

<application id="RestWebService" location="RestWebService.war" name="RestWebService" type="war">
</application>

<basicRegistry>
    <!--    IBM Application Center group.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installapplicationcenter> Ant task for context root '/applicationcenter'] 
    -->
    <group name="appcentergroup">
        <!--    IBM Application Center group member.
        [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installapplicationcenter> Ant task for context root '/applicationcenter'] 
        -->
        <member name="admin"/>

    </group>

    <!--    MobileFirst user.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
    -->
    <user name="configUser_mfpadmin" password="C9Vm6xAktLZh"/>

    <!--    MobileFirst user.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
    -->
    <user name="MfpRESTUser" password="HSQFUiS7bxB8"/>

    <!--    MobileFirst user.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installapplicationcenter> Ant task for context root '/applicationcenter'] 
    -->
    <user name="admin" password="admin"/>




</basicRegistry>


<!--    IBM MobileFirst requires SSL and declared the "defaultKeyStore" default keystore. 
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
This configuration is the minimum one that you need to create an SSL configuration.
With this configuration, the Liberty server creates the keystore and the certificate, 
if it does not exist yet, during the SSL initialization.
The created certificate is a self-signed certificate that is valid for 365 days.
Do not use the certificates that the Liberty server created for production use.
For more information see  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ssl.html 
-->
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="mobilefirst"/>
<!--    MobileFirst JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp.admin.jmx.host" value='"127.0.0.1"'/>
<!--    MobileFirst JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp.admin.jmx.port" value='"9443"'/>
<!--    MobileFirst JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp.admin.jmx.user" value='"MfpRESTUser"'/>
<!--    MobileFirst JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp.admin.jmx.pwd" value='"HSQFUiS7bxB8"'/>
<!--    MobileFirst JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp.topology.platform" value='"Liberty"'/>
<!--    MobileFirst JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp.topology.clustermode" value='"Standalone"'/>

<!--    WebContainer statement.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstruntime> Ant task for context root '/mfp'] 
-->
<webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>

<!--    Executor statement.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
-->
<executor id="default" name="LargeThreadPool"
          coreThreads="200" maxThreads="400" keepAlive="60s"
          stealPolicy="STRICT" rejectedWorkPolicy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!--    Shared JDBC Driver.
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstadmin> Ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'] 
    [Added by IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation <installmobilefirstruntime> Ant task for context root '/mfp'] 
-->
<library id="MobileFirst/JDBC/oracle">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/MobileFirstJDBC/oracle" includes="ojdbc7.jar"/>
</library>

<!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM MobileFirst <installmobilefirstadmin> ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'. -->

<!-- Declare the MobileFirst Administration Service application. -->
<application id="mfpadmin" name="mfpadmin" location="mfp-admin-service.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="mfpadmin">
            <user name="admin"/>

        </security-role>

        <security-role name="mfpdeployer">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="mfpmonitor">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="mfpoperator">
        </security-role>

    </application-bnd>

    <classloader delegation="parentLast" commonLibraryRef="MobileFirst/JDBC/oracle">
        </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the MobileFirst Administration Service. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfpadmin/mfp.config.service.user" value='"configUser_mfpadmin"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfpadmin/mfp.config.service.password" value='"x"'/>


<!-- Declare the IBM MobileFirst Administration database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="mfpadmin/jdbc/mfpAdminDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MobileFirst/JDBC/oracle"/>
    <properties.oracle driverType="thin" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx:x" user="x" password="xxx"/>
</dataSource>

<!-- Declare the MobileFirst Administration Console application. -->
<application id="mfpconsole" name="mfpconsole" location="mfp-admin-ui.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="mfpadmin">
            <user name="admin"/>

        </security-role>

        <security-role name="mfpdeployer">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="mfpmonitor">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="mfpoperator">
        </security-role>

    </application-bnd>

    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the MobileFirst Administration Console. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfpconsole/mfp.admin.endpoint" value='"*://*:*/mfpadmin"'/>


<!-- Declare the MobileFirst Server Artifacts application. -->
<application id="mfp-dev-artifacts" name="mfp-dev-artifacts" location="mfp-dev-artifacts.war" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the MobileFirst Server Artifacts. -->


<!-- Declare the MobileFirst Live Update application. -->
<application id="mfpadminconfig" name="mfpadminconfig" location="mfp-live-update.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="configadmin">
            <user name="configUser_mfpadmin"/>

        </security-role>

    </application-bnd>

    <classloader delegation="parentLast" commonLibraryRef="MobileFirst/JDBC/oracle">
        </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the MobileFirst Live Update. -->


<!-- Declare the IBM MobileFirst Configuration database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="mfpadminconfig/jdbc/ConfigDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MobileFirst/JDBC/oracle"/>
    <properties.oracle driverType="thin" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.163.33.54:1525:SMPS01GM" user="SVMPOMTRM07" password="{xor}Mi8wLG5tbGs="/>
</dataSource>

<!-- End of configuration added by IBM MobileFirst <installmobilefirstadmin> ant task for context root '/mfpadmin'. -->


<!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM MobileFirst <installmobilefirstruntime> ant task for context root '/mfp'. -->

<!-- Declare the MobileFirst Runtime application. -->
<application id="mfp" name="mfp" location="mfp-server.war" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the MobileFirst Runtime. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp/mfp.analytics.url" value='"http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/analytics-service/rest"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp/mfp.analytics.console.url" value='"http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/analytics/console"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp/mfp.analytics.username" value='"admin"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp/mfp.analytics.password" value='"admin"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="mfp/mfp.authorization.server" value='"embedded"'/>


<!-- Declare the IBM MobileFirst Server Runtime database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="mfp/jdbc/mfpDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MobileFirst/JDBC/oracle"/>
    <properties.oracle driverType="thin" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx:x" user="x" password="xxx"/>
</dataSource>

<!-- End of configuration added by IBM MobileFirst <installmobilefirstruntime> ant task for context root '/mfp'. -->


<!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM MobileFirst installer. -->

<!-- Declare the IBM Application Center Console application. -->
<application id="appcenterconsole" name="appcenterconsole" location="appcenterconsole.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
            <group name="appcentergroup"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
</application>

<!-- Declare the IBM Application Center Services application. -->
<application id="applicationcenter" name="applicationcenter" location="applicationcenter.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
            <group name="appcentergroup"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
    <classloader delegation="parentLast"/>
</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the IBM Application Center. -->

<!-- Define the AppCenter services endpoint in order for the AppCenter console to be able to invoke the REST service.
        You need to enable this property if the server is behind a reverse proxy
        or if the context root of the Application Center Services application is different from '/applicationcenter'. -->
<!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.services.endpoint" value='"http://proxyhost:proxyport/applicationcenter"'/> -->
<!-- The directory with binaries of the 'aapt' program, from the Android SDK's platform-tools package. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="android.aapt.dir" value='"/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/tools/android-sdk"'/>
<!-- The protocol of the application resources URI. This property is optional. It is only needed if the protocol of the external and internal URI are different. -->
<!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol" value='"http"'/> -->
<!-- The hostname of the application resources URI. -->
<!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.proxy.host" value='"proxyhost"'/> -->
<!-- The port of the application resources URI. This property is optional. -->
<!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.proxy.port" value="proxyport"/> -->

<!-- Declare the jar files for Oracle access through JDBC. -->
<library id="OracleLib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/oracle" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>

<!-- Declare the IBM Application Center database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/AppCenterDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
    <properties.oracle driverType="thin" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx:x" user="x" password="xxx"/>
</dataSource>

<!-- End of configuration added by IBM MobileFirst installer. -->
```

Comment: Do upload your server.xml

Comment: @VivinK, yes server.xml uploaded. Please help any idea?

Comment: Please confirm - did configuring keystore ( with public certificate from backend) in console, works with JS adapter  and not Java adapter, or was it the same result?

Comment: @VivinK, Yes, previously did with JS adapter and it was fine able configure mutual SSL configuration based on IBM documentation. But it seems not supported for Java adapter

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the "Client" cert of the self-signed cert of the backend into a keystore and then add it using the MFP console.. look at the detailed steps here. 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/01/17/SSL-connection-from-adapters/